# Access ArrayList of object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I declare array list of object table as:

```
  ArrayList<Table> tb=new ArrayList<Table>();
```

But when i try initialize each object as:

```
 tb.get(0)= new Table();
```

I get error 'Variable Expected'. Please help me with the correct way.

Comment: What do you think `get(0)` does and why do you think so?

Comment: doesn't it give first value of the list?

Comment: If your list had a first value.

Comment: Before get, you have to put some value to newly initialized table. Creating a new ArrayList does now populate any values. You have to add those.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: *"doesn't it give first value of the list?"* If it had a first value, yes. And you can't *assign* to values. You can only assign to fields and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding new object to ArrayList is done by function "add":

```
tb.add(0, new Table());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not do `tb.get(0)= new Table();` you need to add values in your array first, then access that value.

Example : following array putting 5 objects of table in your array list.

```
Table table = null;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
table = new Table();
 tb.add(table);
}
```

Then you can access those elements using for loop.

```
 for(int i=-;i<5;i++){
    table = new Table();
    table = tb.get(i);
    // use your table object here
 }
```

Or foreach loop

```
for(Table table : tb){

   // It will give you table object

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of the `get()` method with the ArrayList class is to return the value at the index provided. If you're wanting to add values to an ArrayList, you can use the `add` method it provides.

This will append the value to the end of the list:

```
ArrayList<Table> tb = new ArrayList();
tb.add(new Table());
```

Or, you can append the value to a specified index with the overloaded version:

```
ArrayList<Table> tb = new ArrayList();
tb.add(0, new Table());
```

Be careful with option two as it can throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You can find [documentation on ArrayList here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E))